# Spring JSF Integration pure Java Config (No web.xml)

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-java-config

I'm trying to integrate Spring 4 and JSF 2.x using java config. I am trying to modify the source from the following project to accomplish this.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/tree/master/booking-faces

However, I am stuck can anyone help me. From what I understand I need a FacesServlet but how do i configure that using java config.

pom.xml (Not yet perfect still trying to figure out what I need)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Test</groupId>
<artifactId>TestId</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1</version>
<name>TestId Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <webflow-version>2.3.3.RELEASE</webflow-version>
    <mojarra-version>2.2.5</mojarra-version>
</properties>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Repo</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring webflow -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>${webflow-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- jsf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${mojarra-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${mojarra-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- slf4j logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--  logback -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>TestId</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

AppConfig.java

```
package org.bdo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.bdo")
@Import(value = { WebMvcConfig.class })
public class AppConfig
{

}
```

WebMvcConfig.java

```
package org.bdo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;


@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver faceletsViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JsfView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter simpleControllerHandlerAdapter() {
        return new SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter();
    }

}
```

DispatcherServletInitializer.java

```
package org.config;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener;

public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {  AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/spring/*" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new CharacterEncodingFilter() };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {

        // Use JSF view templates saved as *.xhtml, for use with Facelets
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml");
        // Enable special Facelets debug output during development
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE",
                "Development");
        // Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD",
                "1");
        // Declare Spring Security Facelets tag library
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES",
                "/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml");

        servletContext.addListener(ConfigureListener.class);

        // Let the DispatcherServlet be registered
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

}
```

intro.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:spinner />

</h:body>
</html>
```

Partial Stack Trace

```
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null.
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcher' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher]
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 189 ms
21:38:51.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Servlet 'dispatcher' configured successfully
May 27, 2014 9:38:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Folder (4)\sts-bundle\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1\base-instance\webapps\manager
May 27, 2014 9:38:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Folder (4)\sts-bundle\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1\base-instance\webapps\ROOT
May 27, 2014 9:38:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 27, 2014 9:38:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3271 ms
21:38:53.156 [tomcat-http--4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/SpringJSF/spring/intro]
21:38:53.157 [tomcat-http--4] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringJSF/spring/intro] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:38:53.157 [tomcat-http--4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
May 27, 2014 9:39:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 27, 2014 9:39:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 27, 2014 9:39:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue May 27 21:38:51 CST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
May 27, 2014 9:39:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8d8962: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3c718
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 27 21:38:50 CST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3c718: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,appConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,webMvcConfig,faceletsViewResolver,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter]; root of factory hierarchy
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'webMvcConfig'
21:39:07.403 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'appConfig'
May 27, 2014 9:39:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Comment: I hope I am not the only one interested in integrating spring and jsf with out using a web.xml

Answer (score 1):

in your servlet initializer, use this:

```
/** Faces Servlet */
ServletRegistration.Dynamic facesServlet = servletContext.addServlet("Faces Servlet", FacesServlet.class);
facesServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
facesServlet.addMapping("*.xhtml");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. are you saying i should place this inside my onStartup() method on class DispatcherServletInitializer

Comment: yes, you should place this in your onStartup() method

Comment: it worked for me, let me know if you are having trouble

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, sorry for the late response as I was assigned now to a different task. Ill get back to you once i tested it.